# Vue.js (Quasar) SPA restarts Auth Code Flow on each page reload

Tags: vue.js, auth0, quasar-framework

I have a SPA built with the Quasar Framework (based on Vue.js). The SPA is registered in Auth0 and uses the [auth0-spa-js](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js#readme) library to handle the login via Auth Code Flow. While the login works and I get a token, when I reload the page the Auth Code Flow is started again and the user is redirected to the /authorize endpoint to get a new code, which is then again exchanged for a new token.

To me this does not seem like the correct behaviour. I would have expected that the Auth0 library caches/stores the token in the browser and on page reload checks if there is a valid token already, instead of restarting the Auth Code Flow every time.

Or is that actually the way it should be considering this is a SPA and token storage in the browser is not good.

The code from the boot file:

```
import createAuth0Client from '@auth0/auth0-spa-js';
import axios from 'axios'

export default async ({ app, router, Vue }) => {
    let auth0 = await createAuth0Client({
        domain: '{domain}.auth0.com',
        client_id: '{client_id}',
        audience: '{audience}'
    });

    const isAuthenticated = await auth0.isAuthenticated();
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        // show the gated content
        await afterLogin(auth0, Vue)
        return;
    }

    const query = window.location.search;
    if (query.includes("code=") && query.includes("state=")) {

        // Process the login state
        await auth0.handleRedirectCallback()
        
        await afterLogin(auth0, Vue)

        // Use replaceState to redirect the user away and remove the querystring parameters
        window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, "/");
        
        return
    }

    await auth0.loginWithRedirect({
        redirect_uri: window.location.origin
    });
}

async function afterLogin(auth0, Vue) {
    let user = await auth0.getUser()
    Vue.prototype.$user = user
    Vue.prototype.$auth = auth0

    // let claims = await auth0.getIdTokenClaims()
    // console.log(claims)
    // setAuthHeader(claims.__raw)
    let token = await auth0.getTokenSilently()
    setAuthHeader(token)
}

function setAuthHeader(token) {
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feedback from Auth0 is that this is the expected behaviour.

"If the token is stored in memory, then it will be erased when the page is refreshed. A new token is silently requested via a cookie session."

[Here](https://community.auth0.com/t/new-token-on-each-page-reload/51566) is the link to the original answer

Answer (score 0):

When refreshing you should check if user exists..

```
 const user = await auth0.getUser();
```

You could create an autoCheckUser function at src/boot folder, that can check if user exist every time app created...

Comment: I added the code from the boot file in the question. I'm already calling `await auth0.isAuthenticated()` but it never seems to be true.

Comment: do you have an idea why isAuthenticated() does not return true after login?

Comment: You call const isAuthenticated = await auth0.isAuthenticated(); and then if isAuthenticated true you call afterLogin function and set header but you are not returning anything. Maybe you should not call afterLogin function and just return true, if you have an user why would you create a token again?

Comment: I need to get the access_token somehow, regardless of if I have the user or not, so that I can set it in the HTTP header. And it does not really matter what the afterLogin function returns since I'm calling return after it anyways. So if isAuthenticated is true, then I should have no problems. But for some reason it never is...